# TLS Negotiation issue in OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap

I have the OpenLDAP Master-Slave architecture. One day I have restarted the slapd service in the LDAP Slave and then found the TLS negotiation issue in the Logs. **Before restarting the service, it was working without any issues**

Then I tried to debug the issue, I've found some common problem which will trigger TLS negotiation issue.

1. **The SSL Certificate might get expired** - For my one it's not the case, I've verified that the certificate is valid
2. **Certificate CN name mismatch with the server name** - In my case, my certificate CN=*.example.com and my server names are ldap.example.com & ldap-slave.example.com.
3. **Permission issues in the certificate files** - I've 2 directories (certs - [contains certificate & ca cert & key] , cacert - [Only contain cacert]), both of the directories have read and wrtie permission and owned by the LDAP user.

Here is the configuration used by the slapd.

```
dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcArgsFile: /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
olcDisallows: bind_anon
olcLogLevel:: YW55IA==
olcPidFile: /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
olcRequires: authc
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/example.ca.crt
olcTLSCACertificatePath: /etc/openldap/certs
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/example.crt
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/example.key

dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{0}
olcModulePath: /usr/lib64/openldap
olcModuleLoad: {0}syncprov.la

dn: cn=module{1},cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{1}
olcModulePath: /usr/lib64/openldap
olcModuleLoad: {0}auditlog.la
```

Here is my ldap.conf file

```
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

#BASE   dc=example,dc=com
#URI    ldap://ldap.example.com ldap://ldap-master.example.com:666

#SIZELIMIT  12
#TIMELIMIT  15
#DEREF      never

#TLS_CACERT /etc/openldap/cacerts/example.ca.crt
#TLS_REQCERT demand
TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/openldap/cacerts
#TLS_CACERT /etc/openldap/certs/example.ca.crt
TLS_REQCERT allow
# Turning this off breaks GSSAPI used with krb5 when rdns = false
SASL_NOCANON    on
URI ldaps://ldap.example.com/ ldaps://ldap-slave.example.com/
BASE dc=example,dc=com
```

So please help me to debug the issue.

Comment: What is the log messages

Comment: You do not have TLSDHParamFile; maybe that's the issue other side sends PFS ciphers ???

Answer (score 0):

Can we have the logs with the error to help you?

Also you do not need both olcCACertificatePath and olcCACertificateFile, for me the configuration with only olcCACertficatePath suffice. I do not know if it is the source of your error but you can try to delete one of them.